# TS2307: Cannot find module '_rc-trigger@5.2.0@rc-trigger' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

When I attempt to deploy the application on GitLab, not on my device, this error occurs.
I've just update Antd to the last edition lately, and this has come up.

It only occurred when I tried to build it on the Gitlab

```
ERROR in /usr/src/app/node_modules/antd/es/tooltip/placements.d.ts
ERROR in /usr/src/app/node_modules/antd/es/tooltip/placements.d.ts(16,73):
TS2307: Cannot find module '_rc-trigger@5.2.0@rc-trigger' or its corresponding type declarations.
ERROR in /usr/src/app/node_modules/antd/lib/tooltip/placements.d.ts
ERROR in /usr/src/app/node_modules/antd/lib/tooltip/placements.d.ts(16,73):
TS2307: Cannot find module '_rc-trigger@5.2.0@rc-trigger' or its corresponding type declarations.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! optimax@1.1.6 build:dev: `webpack -p --env.stage --env.optimax --max_old_space_size=512`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es6",
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "types": ["react", "node"],
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "baseUrl": "./",
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

Comment: Can you share your package.json + ci yml file?

Comment: sure @tmhao2005 i can just add package json not yml file

Comment: You said it was occurred on Gitlab CI right? So where is your deployment file?

Comment: added  to comment. @tmhao2005

Comment: This looks like the error from type checking in `node_modules` which is unnecessary for us. Try to turn it off by using `skipLibCheck` instead of DEPRECATED `skipDefaultLibCheck`

Comment: oh thanks.you can add it as an answer. thanks @tmhao2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes we suffer the issue of typing error in `node_modules` which is likely unrelated to our code. Personally I'm keen to turn it off in most use cases.

In your configuration, you also turned it off but it was the value which was deprecated `skipDefaultLibCheck` to be replaced by `skipLibCheck`.

```json
{
  "skipLibCheck": true,
}
```